# ios change subview index runtime

Tags: ios, uiview, z-index

i intend to do some menu with tabs,

if I have the tabs ordered with z index, and i insert each tab with:

> insertSubview:(UIView *) atIndex:(NSInteger)

and by pressing a button on top of them I want to change the tab shown, on top

how can I change the subview index at runtime?

thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`sendSubviewToBack:` and `bringSubviewToFront:` are the methods you are looking for. Another possibility is `exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:` if you want to exchange the layer of two views.

Answer (score 15):

Just insert at new index:

```c
[containerView insertSubview:subview atIndex:newIndex];
```

Comment: You actually don't need to call `[subview removeFromSuperview];`.  The calls `insertSubview:atIndex:`, `insertSubview:aboveSubview:`, and `insertSubview:belowSubview:` will all automatically remove an existing superview if the subview has one.  Here's a quote from UIView's documentation: "Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview."

Answer (score 4):

Swift versions for easy copy paste:

```
insertSubview(myView1, belowSubview: myView2)

insertSubview(myView2, aboveSubview: myView1)

insertSubview(view: myView1, atIndex: 1)
```